# How to change Android Studio tab text color?

Tags: android, android-studio, editor

When using dark mode, editor tab text for changed files are not readable because of color choice. It is blue on gray and it is really annoying for me. I am trying to read the file name like a hypermetropic trying to read. It is definitely not readable. Am I the only one having this problem? I can't find any question about this.

[image: Tabs]

I am not able to find any settings for this. There is a tab color setting under Editor - Color Scheme - General -> Tabs but it had no effect.

[image: Tab Text Color Setting]

Help, please!

Comment: did u tried resetting the android studio to default settings ??

Comment: Yes but no luck. I found how to change it and posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After wasting hours on this, I found the place to change the color.

**Preferences -> Version Control -> File Status Colors -> Modified**

Answer (score 1):

[In this screen u should select the colors and background from the right panel.
likely i have selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMD10.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMD10.png)

Comment: This is not the solution. Please see my own answer. I found where to change.